# Why do I get a ValueError when trying to create an OrderedDict with a single key/value pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the HTML code of a website and I am trying to modify it to change all of the website links with the ones in my home directory. The HTML is stored in a variable called soup. Here are some of the things that I tried:

Example:

website link: `http://Url.com/image1`

modified link: `file://local.html/image1`

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

od = OrderedDict(["http://Url.com", "local"])
replace_all(soup, od)
```

But I get this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Do you guys know how to make it happen?

Comment: OrderedDict expects to get a list of pairs.  You are giving it a list of singles.  You could use `od = OrderedDict([["http://Url.com", "local"]])`.  You don't need an `OrderedDict` here, but even if you did, standard `dict`s are now ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to operate on a string of the whole HTML source using regex.

```py
import re

reg = re.compile(r'http://url.com')

s = """
<a href="http://url.com"></a>
<img src="http://url.com/goodpic.jpg"/>
"""

print(reg.sub('local', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because the OrderedDict constructor is not receiving the correct arguments. Regardless though, it seems that you don't need a dictionary structure, because the `replace` method takes care of the replacement for you. So you can just do this:

```
def replace_all(text, to_replace):
    for old, new in to_replace:
        text = text.replace(old, new)
    return text
to_replace = [("http://Url.com", "local"), ("url2_old", "url2_new"), ]
replace_all(soup, to_replace)
```